# Responsive Image with fixed height

Tags: html, css

i would like to have responsive image with a fixed height.

Here is my html :

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="img">
       <img src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/16/1461065658-b-v-s.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="img">
       <img src="http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/16/1461065665-kfp3.jpg">
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css :

```
.col-md-6 {
   width: 50%;
   float: left;
 }

.img {
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   height: 290px;
}

.img img {
   max-width: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/23o81xrb/

As u can see, .img has an height of 290px and that should stay like that, but when we reduce the window, images aren't adapted. I would like to have like a "zoom" on my image so they can keep 290px height and be adapted in width.

Sorry for my "bad" english, hope u understood.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It can't be responsive AND have fixed values...it's not logical

Comment: @Paulie_D At least without distorting the image.

Comment: Perhaps with "zoom" he means image clipping on resize....

Comment: Perhaps - https://jsfiddle.net/794w2kmb/

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, that's almost that but is that possible to do that without touching the width ? Like when u reduce the window, image is zooming inside herself ?

Answer (score 3):

If you use *img* tag, use can use **object-fit** property in CSS3 as below :

```
.col-md-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.img {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 290px;
}

.img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: Nice idea! See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit and https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create zoom effect with fixed height in img tags, **good luck**!

But, If you use your images as background, you may fix to height and you may get a solution like you want. Here is an example:

```css
.col-md-6 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
.img {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 290px;
}
.img.first {
  background-image: url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/16/1461065658-b-v-s.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.img.second {
  background-image: url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/16/1461065665-kfp3.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.img img {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width;
  100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="img first">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="img second">
  </div>
</div>
```