# Image being stretched with Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I got a `div` containing one image and 5 text elements in a row, which I've spaced evenly using `Flexbox`. All paragraphs look as expected, but the image is stretched as soon as I change the width or height to anything other than `100%`. I have used `align-items: center` and `align-self: center`.

```css
section {
  display: block;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.result {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  height: 70px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.result img {
  width: auto;
  align-self: center;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="result">
    <img src="transavia.png" alt="Transavia">
    <p><b>19:45 - 21:05</b><br>April 1st</p>
    <p><b>AMS-ORY</b><br>Transavia</p>
    <p><b>Direct</b><br>1 h 20 min</p>
    <p><b>SEK 611</b><br>Economy class</p>
    <h3 class="sixseven">7/10</h3>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: what is the size of your image ?

Comment: @AymanMorsy 320x320 for this specific one, however it happens for all images with varying sizes that I've tried.

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior when I run something similar locally. Perhaps I'm not understanding which `height` or `width` you are changing that produces the image stretching?

Comment: This Q may help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717464/responsive-image-with-fixed-height/52153316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the image is stretched as soon as I change the width or height to anything other than 100%.**
This is because you have assigned a fixed height so the height must be 30px... now if you assign width of 100%, the image will be stretched because i am using a very large image...

You have the following choices:

- in the blue section... i have a put a huge image (via a public URL) to show the behavior with a % point for width (while height remains auto) - this would require media queries to get the best result on a mobile device
- in the green section... i have a put a huge image (via a public URL) to show the behavior with a size in pixel - this would result in a consistent result on a mobile device also
- in the pink section... i have used your fixed height and any width i use, i will get a stretched image, because the image is large and height is fixed !!!
- in the gray section... i have used a minimum-height and since the image is large, it goes to its default size (because it is respecting the min-height condition)

```css
section {
  display: block;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

section:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightpink;
}

section:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.result {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  min-height: 70px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section:nth-child(1) .result img {
  width: 4%;
  align-self: center;
}

section:nth-child(2) .result img {
  width: 38px;
  align-self: center;
}

section:nth-child(3) .result img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 10%;
  align-self: center;
}

section:nth-child(4) .result img {
  min-height: 30px;
  align-self: center;
}

.result>* {
  border: 1px dotted yellow;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="result">
    <img src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg" alt="Transavia">
    <p><b>19:45 - 21:05</b><br>April 1st</p>
    <p><b>AMS-ORY</b><br>Transavia</p>
    <p><b>Direct</b><br>1 h 20 min</p>
    <p><b>SEK 611</b><br>Economy class</p>
    <h3 class="sixseven">7/10</h3>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="result">
    <img src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg" alt="Transavia">
    <p><b>19:45 - 21:05</b><br>April 1st</p>
    <p><b>AMS-ORY</b><br>Transavia</p>
    <p><b>Direct</b><br>1 h 20 min</p>
    <p><b>SEK 611</b><br>Economy class</p>
    <h3 class="sixseven">7/10</h3>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="result">
    <img src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg" alt="Transavia">
    <p><b>19:45 - 21:05</b><br>April 1st</p>
    <p><b>AMS-ORY</b><br>Transavia</p>
    <p><b>Direct</b><br>1 h 20 min</p>
    <p><b>SEK 611</b><br>Economy class</p>
    <h3 class="sixseven">7/10</h3>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="result">
    <img src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/JumboMob.jpg" alt="Transavia">
    <p><b>19:45 - 21:05</b><br>April 1st</p>
    <p><b>AMS-ORY</b><br>Transavia</p>
    <p><b>Direct</b><br>1 h 20 min</p>
    <p><b>SEK 611</b><br>Economy class</p>
    <h3 class="sixseven">7/10</h3>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Great, thank you. Works as expected when applied. However, the min-height instead of fixed height makes the containers much larger than expected. Why does this happen?

Comment: if we do a `min-height`, and the image is large - it will default to its original size and the div will increase in size to accommodate it... let me update the answer with this scenario